# How to reverse a loop

Tags: java

So basically my assignment was to print a list of stars.

```
public class Practice_6_2
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  final int MAX_ROWS = 10;

  for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
  {
     for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++)
        System.out.print ("*");

     System.out.println();
  }
}
}
```

But when it prints, it is actually the opposite. How would I fix this?

Edit:

When I run the program, it will print one star on the first line, two stars on the second, and so forth until it reaches the tenth line. I need it to print ten stars on the first line, nine on the second, and so forth. Kind of reversing it.

Comment: Please describe the expected output. Otherwise it's impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps you will get what you want by swaping the two `for` statements, but without a precise description of what you want, it's not possible to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse the direction you iterate on `row`. Change

```
for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
```

to something like

```
for (int row = MAX_ROWS; row >= 1; row--)
```

to start at `MAX_ROWS` and descend to `1`.